# Set row height for only one tableView and ignore other tableView's in heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I had a TableViewController with one TableView which had it's rows set dynamically with **auto layout.**

I've added another TableView to the Controller which is used for a menu. It's row heights need to be set at 65.

The problem is, in **heightForRowAtIndexPath**. I know how to just return 65 for this tableView menu's rows. But I'm not sure how to let **auto layout** do it's thing for the other tableView still.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Here's my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView is YALContextMenuTableView {
        return 65
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Adapt Auto Layout and self-sizing for your menu tableView cell, so its constraints size its height (to 65), or
- Continue to use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Return a height of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for your non-menu tableView cells, which will let the system self-size those cells.

Self-sizing would be the preferred way to go, as it works well in conjunction with Dynamic Type and Adaptive UI.

Comment: Returning UITableViewAutomaticDimension seemed to be what worked for me, thank you so much ☺️

Answer (score 6):

You can use `super` to use the implementation of this method by `UITableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView is YALContextMenuTableView {
        return 65
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)
    }
}
```